# Regex hangs trying to find match

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match an assignment string in VB code (as in I'm passing in text that is VB code into my program that's written in C#). The assignment string that I'm trying to match is something for example like

```
CustomClassInitializer(someParameter, anotherParameter, someOtherClassAsParameterWithInitialization()).SomeProperty = 7
```

and I realize that's rather complex, but it actually isn't far off from some of the real text I'm trying to match.

In order to do so I wrote a Regex. This Regex:

```
@"[\w,.]+\(([\w,.]*\(*,* *\)*)+ = "
```

which correctly matches. The problem is it becomes VERY slow (with timeouts), which I've researched and found is probably because of "backtracking". One of the suggested solutions to help with backtracking in general was to add "?>" to the regex, which I think would go in this position:

```
[\w,.]+\(?>([\w,.]*\(*,* *\)*)+ =
```

but this no longer matches properly.

I'm fairly new to Regex, so I imagine that there is a much better pattern. What is it please? Or how can I improve my times in general?

Helpful notes:

1. I'm only interested in position 0 of the string I'm searching for a
   match in. My code is "if (isMatch && match.index == 0) { ... }. Can
   I tell it to only check position 0 and if it's not a match move on?
2. The reason I use all the 0 or more things is the match could be as simple as CustomClass() = new CustomClass(), and as complicated as the above or perhaps a bit worse. I'm trying to get as many cases as possible.
3. This Regex is interested in "[\w,.]+(" and then "whatever may be inside the parentheses" (I tried to think of what all could be inside them based on the fact that it's valid VB code) until you get to the close parenthesis and then " = ". Perhaps I can use a wildcard for literally anything until it get's to ") = " in the string? - Like I said, fairly new to Regex.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please post an example of positive case, which you want to detect with regex.

Comment: @RehanHaider I can on Monday. I'm writing this at work and didn't think to copy an actual case. Sorry.

Comment: No Problem, in this case I'll not be able to help you :)

Comment: @RehanHaider I understand. Hopefully on Monday you'll be able to :)

Comment: After reading all your comments, it looks as if you may just use [`^[a-zA-Z_][\w,.]*\(.* = `](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5ba-zA-Z_%5d%5b%5cw%2c.%5d*%5c%28.*+%3d+&i=CustomClassInitializer%28someParameter%2c+anotherParameter%2c+someOtherClassAsParameterWithInitialization%28%29%29.SomeProperty+%3d+7%0d%0aCustomClass%28%29+%3d+new+CustomClass%28%29&o=m). Note that parsing code with regex is error prone. Only use it if you know the code is written in a consistent way.

Comment: Probably because your regex sucks or you are trying to use it on something non regular.

Comment: The big problem you are having is this part `(?:[\w,.]*\(*,*[ ]*\)*)+` Everything in there is optionally quantified with a `*` while the overall cluster is quantified with a `+`. This is causing the backtracking problem. You have to reverse it. Take the inside portion and divide it up with alternations, where within each alternation is a _required_ portion. Then make the overall cluster optional with the `*`. That will fix your problem The reason nobody here can help you is that it is unknown the proper form that you need.

Comment: @Mardoxx As I mentioned, I'm new to regex. I also said that I imagine there is a better regex. Your comment doesn't provide anything constructive to the question/discussion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do what you want.  Normally, I like to be more specific than .*, but it is working correctly.  Note that I am using the Multi-line option.

```
^.*=\s*.+$
```

Here is a working example in RegExStorm.net [example](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E.*%3D%5Cs*.%2B%24&i=CustomClass%28%29%20%3D%20new%20CustomClass%28%29%0D%0ACustomClassInitializer%28someParameter%2C%20anotherParameter%2C%20someOtherClassAsParameterWithInitialization%28%29%29.SomeProperty%20%3D%207%0D%0ANonMatchingMethod%28foo%29%0D%0Abar%20%3D%20foo%0D%0Axxx%3D9%0D%0Axxxx%20%3D%20word%20%3D%20%22some%20text%22%0D%0Abar%20%3D%20foo%28bar%29%0D%0AmultilineStatement%20%3D%0D%0AworksToo&o=m)